# Editing attribute table in ArcGIS Explorer?

Tags: attribute-table, editing, arcgis-explorer

I currently need to edit and add data to attribute tables in Explorer.

Is this even possible?

I am new to Explorer but am proficient in ArcMap. I know how to edit data with ArcMap using the editor feature. The table in explorer came from a geodatabase if that helps.

Comment: I remember editing shapefile dbf using vb in Excel and ArcReader had no problem with that. If you know database structure the answer is yes, but effforts are too great.